# Check if ruby keyword argument is passed (RUBY)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to test if a keyword argument was passed.

```
def test(:name, :zip)
  if name.key.present?
     #then do stuff
  end
end
```

I do not want to just check for nil, but because if nil is intentionally passed

`test(name: nil, zip: 10011)`, I would like the method to handle the hash differently, then if the keyword pair was never passed.`test(zip: 10011)`

#### How do I check if a keyword/vale pair was passed into the method?

Comment: Currently both keyword arguments are required, meaning they are both always passed. I guess you meant `def test(name: nil, zip: nil)` making both keyword arguments optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code does not work, keyword arguments are defined as `key: defaultvalue`

You may define an "unpossible" value as default and check for it.
"unpossible" means a value that will be never used as an argument.

```
def test(name: :just_some_stupd_content, zip: nil)
  if name == :just_some_stupd_content
    puts 'Name is not set'
  else
    puts 'Name is set'
     #then do stuff
  end
end
  
test(name: nil, zip: 10011)
test(zip: 10011)
```

This logic will not work when you call it with

```
test(name: :just_some_stupd_content, zip: 10011)
```

So it is not bullet proof, but I think it is a useable way.

### Solution with ruby >= 2.1

Ruby 2.1 introduced required keyword arguments, which are defined with a trailing colon:

```
def test(name:, zip: nil)
    puts 'Name is set'
end
  
test(name: nil, zip: 10011)
test(zip: 10011)  #raises missing keyword: name (ArgumentError)
```

If is depending on your need, if this solution fits better.

Comment: When I need to check if the user has provided a value (but still having the argument optional) I mostly use `:"\0"` (NULL symbol) which has essentially the same function as `:just_some_stupd_content`.

Comment: UNDEFINED = Object.new was what I ended up using. thank you

Answer (score 1):

A number of things wrong here.

First, you're declaring your method incorrectly. Do not use symbols for argument names. If I try to run the method definition through RSpec with argument names as symbols, I get:

```
12:20:27 - INFO - Running: spec/so/optional_args_spec.rb

An error occurred while loading ./spec/so/optional_args_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: __send__(method, file)

SyntaxError:
  [REDACTED]/optional_args_spec.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting ')'
    def test(:name, :zip)
             ^
  [REDACTED]/optional_args_spec.rb:24: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
# [REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@so/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:2053:in `load'
# [REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@so/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:2053:in `load_file_handling_errors'
# [REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@so/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1560:in `block in load_spec_files'
# [REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@so/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1558:in `each'
# [REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@so/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1558:in `load_spec_files'
# [REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@so/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:98:in `setup'
# [REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@so/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
# [REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@so/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
# [REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@so/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
# [REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@so/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
# [REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@so/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
# [REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@so/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
# [REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@so/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
# [REDACTED]/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@so/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
# 
#   Showing full backtrace because every line was filtered out.
#   See docs for RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_exclusion_patterns and
#   RSpec::Configuration#backtrace_inclusion_patterns for more information.
No examples found.

Finished in 0.00027 seconds (files took 0.42065 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

Just do:

```
def test(name, zip)
end
```

Second, if you're wanting to do:

```
test(name: nil, zip: 10011)
```

You'll get an error because you've specified two arguments (`name`, and `zip`) and you're only passing one (the hash: `{name: nil, zip: 10011}`). So, do:

```
def test(args)

end
```

Now you can do:

```
def test(args)
  if args.key?(:name) 
    # then do stuff...
  end
end
```

Comment: @3limin4t0r - When I try to run the method as defined (using symbols as argument names), RSpec throws a `SyntaxError`. Can you provide a link to documentation where symbols are used as argument names, for my edification?

Comment: You're correct, that should be `def test(name:, zip:)`, my mistake.